# Maven : how to order multiple execution of a goal in the same phase in a specfic order

Tags: maven, maven-3

I want my "pre-integration-test" phase to be the following execution of goals, in this specfic order.

**PHASE : pre-integration-test**

- get a spring boot jar (maven-dependency-plugin:copy)
- get-a-port (build-helper-maven-plugin:reserve-network-port)
- display-port (maven-antrun-plugin:run #1)
- start-server (exec-maven-plugin)
- wait-for startup (maven-antrun-plugin:run #2)

Is there any way to do this using Maven 3?

The problem that I am facing, is that **"maven-antrun-plugin:run" 1 & 2** will always be run one after the other, because they are defined in the same plugin element :

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>display-port</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo>Displaying value of 'tomcat.http.port' property</echo>
                                <echo>[tomcat.http.port] ${tomcat.http.port}</echo>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>wait-for-startup</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <sleep seconds="10" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Right now, the only way I have found to do this is to duplicate the "maven-antrun-plugin:" plugin element in the pom file.
But this gets me a warning

```
'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration
```

For the scope of this question, I am not looking for a work-around, such as changing the plugin for the  "display-port" or "wait-for startup", or changing the phase on of the goals.

I just want to understand if what I am trying to do is possible or not.

Comment: What kind of test do you need to do related to Spring Boot related to tomcat/display port? Furthermore you know spring-boot-maven-plugin:run ? I don't understand why you need to do `dependency:copy`?

Comment: Whatever I am trying to do, the question is about Maven ordering. And I quote myself : "For the scope of this question, I am not looking for a work-around, such as changing the plugin for the "display-port" or "wait-for startup", or changing the phase on of the goals."

Answer (score 1):

If multiple executions have the same phase, then the first one to be executed will be the built-in one (e.g. maven-compiler-plugin) whose id is default-something, then the other executions will take place in the order they appear in your pom file.